# In Flutter Application How to do test automation for a registration form opened through a server url like localhost.9xxxxx etc

Tags: flutter, automated-tests, flutterdriver

In Flutter Application How to  test a registration form opened through a server url like localhost.9xxxxx etc I want to do test automation of form filling .

I have a flutter mobile and web application where in which users are allowed to create account for the first time and members who already created account can login using email or username and password.

Please help with test automation for the above.

Note : My link is a hosting server  url.

I want to perform flutter test automation  for opening the url and form filling like creation of account and Sign in please help me with all the above

Built a basic url_launcher  and webview flutter application which opens a normal url like yahoo.com  and google.com and performed test using flutter_driver and test  dependancies.

````
  > import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    > import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
    > 
    > class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    > const MainScreen({super.key});
    > 
    >   @override
    > State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
    > }
    > 
    > ```
    > class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
    > 
    > Future<void> _launchURL(String url) async {
    > final Uri uri = Uri(scheme: "https", host: url);
    > if(!await launchUrl(
    > uri,
    > mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
    >     )) {
    > throw "Can not launch url";
    >     }
    >   }
    > 
    >   @override
    > Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    > return Scaffold(
    > body: Center(
    > child: Container(
    > height: 50,
    > width: 120,
    > color: Colors.red,
    > child: Center(
    > child: GestureDetector(
    > onTap: () {
    > _launchURL("www.google.com");
    >               },
    > child: const Text("Launch URL"),
    >             ),
    >           ),
    >         ),
    >       ),
    >     );
    >   }
    > }
````

For Testing

> import 'package:flutter_driver/flutter_driver.dart';
> import 'package:test/test.dart';
>
> void main() {
>
> group('URL Opening Tests', () {
> FlutterDriver? driver;
>
> setUpAll(() async {
> driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
> });
>
> tearDownAll(() async {
> if (driver != null) {
> driver?.close();
> }
> });
>
> test('Open URL Using url_launcher', () async {
> await driver?.tap(find.byType('ElevatedButton'));

> ```
> });
> ```
>
> });
> }

Comment: Please post the code in a code block (`{}` button), not as a quote.

Comment: Now able to access local host url but to flutter automation test using selenium webdiver package in flutter with the help of chromedriver

Comment: I want to do automation testing on external application like browser url containing Sign up form and sign In Form

Answer (score 0):

At last I have successfully  achieved it by using chrome for Testing Browser and same version chrome webdriver but it has limitations like we cannot launch the application on local host directly but after running the application or compiling the application it will be hosted on a local host port and then we have to run  that port on chrome for Testing Browser.